iPhone angular 19 material text color in light mode is white
Desktop, Android phone is fine. I am using Chrome to test it.
By default, it's light.
The text is white on iPhone both with Chrome and Safari.
I had no clue why.
See light-mode:

See dark-mode which is OK:

Here is the config which is pretty much the basic default suggest by Angular Material
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
html {
    height: 100%;
    color-scheme: light dark;
    @include mat.theme((
            color: mat.$azure-palette,
            typography: Roboto,
            density: 0));
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    //font-family: mat.get-theme-typography($my-theme);
}

body.dark-mode {
    color-scheme: dark;
    background-color: #222222;
    color: white;
}


I found the problem myself. Seems fixed it. Test it on my phone and desktop, all good now.
I changed the line within html to :
color-scheme: light;

Everything now is good.
I don't know what the old way light dark are for.
The issue seems that because my phone was set in dark color, Angular Material confusingly picks the "dark" color when it renders the app in light mode
